# Web Scraping with BS4 - Can you sort this out?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Can you fix this code for me? This is giving me a erroneous message like,

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Can anyone please help me on this? Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url="https://www.cse.lk/pages/trade-summary/trade-summary.component.html"

data  = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')

cse = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Company Name", "Symbol", "Share Volume", "Trade Volume", "Previous Close (Rs.)", "Open (Rs.)", "High (Rs.)", "Low (Rs.)", "**Last Traded Price (Rs.)", "Change (Rs.)", "Change Percentage (%)"])
for row in soup.find_all('tbody').find_all('tr'): ##for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    Company_Name = col[0].text
    Symbol = col[1].text
    Share_Volume = col[2].text
    Trade_Volume = col[3].text
    Previous_Close = col[4].text
    Open = col[5].text
    High = col[6].text
    Low = col[7].text
    Last_Traded_Price = col[8].text
    Change = col[9].text
    Change_Percentage = col[10].text
    cse = cse.append({"Company Name":Company_Name,"Symbol":Symbol,"Share Volume":Share_Volume,"Trade Volume":Trade_Volume,"Previous Close (Rs.)":Previous_Close,"Open (Rs.)":Open,"High (Rs.)":High,"Low (Rs.)":Low,"**Last Traded Price (Rs.)":Last_Traded_Price,"Change (Rs.)":Change,"Change Percentage (%)":Change_Percentage}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from external URL via Javascript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use this example how to load it:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.cse.lk/api/tradeSummary"

data = requests.post(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["reqTradeSummery"])

print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)
```

Prints:

```
       id                                                       name      symbol  quantity  percentageChange  change    price  previousClose     high      low  lastTradedTime    issueDate      turnover  sharevolume  tradevolume     marketCap  marketCapPercentage     open  closingPrice  crossingVolume  crossingTradeVol  status
0     204                                      ABANS ELECTRICALS PLC  ABAN.N0000       317          4.184704    7.25   180.50         173.25   183.00   172.00   1626944252441  01/JAN/1984  1.256363e+06         7012           44  9.224561e+08                  0.0   179.00        180.50            7012                44       0
1    1845                                          ABANS FINANCE PLC  AFSL.N0000        89         -3.225806   -1.00    30.00          31.00    30.10    30.00   1626944124197  27/JUN/2011  1.160916e+06        38652           11  1.996847e+09                  0.0    30.10         30.00           38652                11       3
2    2065                                     ACCESS ENGINEERING PLC   AEL.N0000       500         -0.432900   -0.10    23.00          23.10    23.40    22.90   1626944388726  27/MAR/2012  1.968675e+07       855534          264  2.300000e+10                  0.0    23.10         23.00          855534               264       0
3     472                                             ACL CABLES PLC   ACL.N0000      1000         -0.963855   -0.40    41.10          41.50    41.70    40.90   1626944397450  01/JAN/1976  3.037800e+07       738027          421  9.846521e+09                  0.0    41.50         41.10          738027               421       0
4     406                                           ACL PLASTICS PLC  APLA.N0000        20          0.842697    2.25   269.25         267.00   272.75   266.00   1626943847820  05/APR/1995  1.436916e+06         5333           26  1.134216e+09                  0.0   272.75        269.25            5333                26       0

...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice);

[image]

Comment: thanks @Andrej . Can I know the reason for using an API link for the url location instead of the given one?

Comment: @SnyderFox The URL `https://www.cse.lk/pages/trade-summary/trade-summary.component.html` doesn't contain the data. Instead, it uses JavaScript to connect to `https://www.cse.lk/api/tradeSummary` and load the date dynamically. So when you parse the first URL with `bs4`, you don't see the data.

Comment: thanks. How did you convert the link  to an api one? im new to python. thats why...

Comment: @SnyderFox When you open Firefox Developer Tools->Network Tab (Chrome has something similar) and do reload, you will see all requests the page is doing. One of these requests is this API url with the data.

Comment: Hi Andrej, Can I know one thing pls? How did you take "reqTradeSummery" under df = pd.DataFrame(data["reqTradeSummery"])? where can i find that?